# Python joining strings and array's contents

Tags: python, arrays, string

I've been trying to use some loops to join together a string with an arrays content like the example below:

```
Array's content for each index:
array[0] = [bla,bla,bla,bla]
array[1] = [ble,ble,ble,ble]
array[2] = [bli,bli,bli,bli]

String i want to add:
new_string = ",ok"
```

I want to get the following output:

```
bla,bla,bla,bla,ok
```

if i try something like the codes below i get the following outputs

```
print (str(array[0]) + new_string)

Output:
bla,bla,bla,bla
,OK

newer_string = str(array[0]) + new_string
print (newer_string)

Output:
[bla,bla,bla,bla\n],ok
```

So i am not really sure on how to get the result i want. Also, each content of the array is kinda huge and the examples above are merely a simplified version of what they contain, however the string i want to add is simply a word or two.

EDIT:

Here is a example of one of my indexed arrays. Each of them has a delimited line that i got from a csv file.

```
Array[0] = [11111,22222,88888888888,2018-01-01 00:00:00,Document,Place,type1,type2,COMPLET SUCESS,,PostPaid,No Extra,,20,N,,,,,,,,,,,9876543321,No,R,P,november,proxy ,2018-01-01 16:01:01]
```

Comment: You should put in the effort of at least providing real example data...

Comment: it is basically not that different, it just much longer like a line delimited by 20 "," or so.

Comment: You are required to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It isn't clear, but it looks like your *list* contains strings like this: `"[bla,bla,bla,bla\n]"` which doesn't seem like a good idea. Rather, the list should  contain *lists* like `['bla','bla','bla','bla']`

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example added

Comment: This isn't an MCVE, for example, `Array` is not defined, and your example list is not a valid literal, containing many undefined names like `Document` and `Place`... but anyway, you should be *parsing* your csv, not just dumping each line into a list of lines. Then you could simply append your extra value trivially...

Comment: I was planing on saving these outputs into a secondary file? Should i them use a while to open 2 files at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join string element from an array use the **[join](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/data-types/python-join-examples)** method

**Example:**

```
a = ['bla','bla','bla','bla']
print(",".join(a) + " ok")
```

**Result**:

```
bla,bla,bla,bla ok
```

Comment: This is probably correct but the string i saved on each indexed array have a "\n" at the end so i'll just have to find a way around that.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: YWC. And to remove the newline char use "bla,bla,bla,bla ok \n".replace('\n', "")

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> array = [["bla","bla","bla","bla"],["ble","ble","ble","ble"],["bli","bli","bli","bli"]]
>>> for element in array:
...     element.append("ok")
...     ",".join(element)
```

or if you don't want to modify your arrays:

```
>>> array = [["bla","bla","bla","bla"],["ble","ble","ble","ble"],["bli","bli","bli","bli"]]
>>> for element in array:
...     ",".join(element) + ",ok"
```